# PIL - make 1 PNG from JPG and PNG frame

Tags: python, image, png, python-imaging-library

I have 2 images:

- PNG (99x97) with white, rotated frame and rest is in full transparency.
- JPG - is my generated thumbnail (80x80)

Now I want to put thumbnail into my frame so it looks like some kind of painting. What should I do?

**EDIT:**

I forgot to add, that picture must be under the frame.

[Frame image](http://i43.tinypic.com/30j1yro.png)

I have some script but it shows only a frame. There is no picture in it :/

```
import Image, ImageDraw

img_size = (99,97)
im = Image.open('logo.jpg')
picture = im.crop((0,0,80,80))
frame = Image.open('thumb-frame.png')
picture = picture.convert('RGBA')
background = Image.new('RGBA', img_size, (255, 255, 255, 0))
background.paste(picture, (10,9))
background.paste(frame, (0,0))
background.save('logocopy.png', 'PNG')
```

EDIT:

Problem solved. I had to add alpha mask to .paste()

```
import Image

im = Image.open('logo.jpg')
picture = im.crop((0,0,80,80))
picture = picture.convert('RGBA')
frame = Image.open('thumb-frame.png')
background = Image.new('RGBA', frame.size, (255, 255, 255, 0))
background.paste(picture, (10,9))
background.paste(frame, (0,0), frame)
background.save('logocopy.png', 'PNG')
```

Comment: what did you try ? We're not going to write the code for you, but we can help you with problems in your code :)

Comment: @CédricJulien look on my edited post.

Comment: First draw a picture, then draw a frame above that picture. If frame has transparency set right, you should get what you want.

Comment: @race1 as i wrote:  ...it shows only a frame. There is no picture in it :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. This should take original picture and paste transparent frame image above it. Both pictures should be 100x100, but you can add needed resizing.

```
from PIL import Image

frame = Image.open('frame.png')
img = Image.open('image.jpg')

img_dest = img.copy().convert('RGBA')
img_dest.paste(frame, (0, 0, 100, 100), frame)

img_dest = img_dest.convert('RGB') # Optional, to remove transparency info

img_dest.save('output.png')
```